# In Python, how does a user defined object look in memory?

Tags: python

I was surprised when I learned that a user defined object by itself takes up some memory (48 bytes), and is stored at a separate address as compared to the object's attributes. So I want to understand how a user defined object looks in memory.

Comment: It's entirely implementation dependent. But in general, in CPython, an object has a reference to a dict that stores its attributes, rather than the attributes being "embedded" in the object itself.